How can I close a popup opened during my script?
I have a script that performs tasks on a page. One task opens a popup but I'm unable to close it.

color="accent" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-button mat-button-base mat-accent">... is not clickable at point (684, 847). Other element would receive the click: 
(Session info: chrome=124.0.6367.61)

My code
# Import necessary modules
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import csv
import time

# Set up Chrome service
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Initialize Chrome WebDriver with the service
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get("https://mmiconnect.in/app/exhibition/catalogue/ep2023")

# Close the initial popup if present
try:
    # Find and click the close button if it's clickable
    close_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "close-button")))
    close_button.click()
except:
    # If close button not found, pass
    pass

# List to store the scraped data
siteData = []

# Iterate over pages
for nav in range(1, 33):
    for i in range(1, 750):
        try:
            # Find and click on the buttons
            listing = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'center')))
            lists = listing.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='courses']//button[contains(@class, 'mat-focus-indicator')]")

            # Iterate over the buttons
            for listss in lists:
                try:
                    # Click on the button
                    listss.click()
                    # Wait for the popup to appear
                    time.sleep(2)
                    
                    # Check if the popup is still open
                    if EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "mat-dialog-3"))(driver):
                        # Wait for the popup to appear
                        popup_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mat-dialog-3")))
                        
                        # Scrape data from the popup
                        table = popup_element.find_element(By.ID, "customers")
                        rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
                        table_data = []
                        for row in rows:
                            cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
                            row_data = [cell.text for cell in cells]
                            table_data.append(row_data)

                        # Write table data to CSV
                        with open("mmei.csv", mode='a', newline='') as file:
                            writer = csv.writer(file)
                            writer.writerows(table_data)

                        # Execute JavaScript to click the "Close" button within the popup
                        close_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@aria-label, 'Close dialog')]")))
                        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_button)
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    # Print error if any
                    print("Error processing popup:", e)
                    pass
                
        except Exception as e:
            # Print error if any
            print("Error iterating over pages:", e)
            continue

# Quit the driver
driver.quit()


need help for popup not closed

You never stated which close button isn't closing?

When I ran your code, nothing happened. It never clicked on the first "View details" link, etc. and never output anything so I rewrote it.
Some suggestions...

As of Selenium 4.6, you no longer need to install and use a DriverManager because Selenium has one built in. I removed all the unnecessary code related to DriverManager.

You declared WebDriverWait a number of times in the script. You can instead just declare it once and reuse it, e.g.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "close-button"))).click()


If you aren't going to use a variable more than once, there's not much point in declaring it. Removing these instances will clean up your code.
 close_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "close-button")))
 close_button.click()

can be
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "close-button"))).click()


Instead of hardcoding numbers to loop over in your ranges, grab the elements off the page and count them.

It's not a good practice to throw everything inside a try-except... it's also not a good practice to capture at the generic Exception level. What you end up doing is eating all exceptions hiding what's actually going wrong. Leave out the try-except and learn to read the exception messages. Once you've got your script highly polished, then put try-except back in and only catch the specific exceptions you are going to handle, e.g.
except TimeoutException:


Using time.sleep() is a bad practice. Instead use WebDriverWait as you do elsewhere.

Don't check to see if an element is visible using
if EC.visibility_of_element_located(...):

instead wait for it to be visible. That way you are assured that it will be there.

In one case you are waiting for the popup to appear but are using EC.presence_of_element_located(). Presence means that the element exists in the DOM, not that it's visible. Instead use EC.visibility_of_element_located().

wait.until() returns the element(s) waited on... so use that.
listing = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'center')))
lists = listing.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='courses']//button[contains(@class, 'mat-focus-indicator')]")

becomes
lists = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='courses']//button[contains(@class, 'mat-focus-indicator')]")))


You are opening and writing to the CSV inside the loop. Move that code until after the loop and when all scraping is done, the CSV will be written once saving lots of time and hard drive thrashing.


Using this advice, here's the working code
# Import necessary modules
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

# Initialize Chrome WebDriver with the service
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get("https://mmiconnect.in/app/exhibition/catalogue/ep2023")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# Close the initial popup if present
try:
    # Find and click the close button if it's clickable
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "close-button"))).click()
except:
    # If close button not found, pass
    pass

# List to store the scraped data
site_data = []

# Find all View details links
view_details_links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button/span[text()='View details']")))

# Iterate over the links
for view_details_link in view_details_links:
    # Click on the link
    view_details_link.click()
    
    # Wait for the TABLE in the popup to appear
    table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "customers")))

    # Wait for TABLE content to load
    while True:
        text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#customers td.field-content").text
        if text is not "":
            break
    
    # Scrape data from the popup
    rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    table_data = []
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
        row_data = [cell.text for cell in cells]
        print(row_data)
        table_data.append(row_data)
    
    site_data.append(table_data)

    # Close the popup
    close = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Close']")
    close.click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(close))

# Write table data to CSV
with open("mmei.csv", mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(site_data)

# Quit the driver
driver.quit()

This code successfully writes the data to the CSV.

and how it will work on the no of pages like i have 33 no of pages

Your question was how to close the popup. My code addressed that so this question is answered. If you want to loop through all the pages then you'll need to add a loop.

Function to move to the next page
def move_to_next_page(wait):
try:
next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Next page"]')))
next_button.click()
return True
except TimeoutException:
print("Next page button not found or timed out.")
return False

using this but is going the next page but table data not coming properly

The question posted has been answered. What you are asking now needs to be posted as a new question.
